# When application is maximized, Can't click certain textboxes or comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, focus, maximize

When i maximize my application and try to set focus or click into certain textboxes or comboboxes I am unable to. After running my mouse over these objects many times I can sometimes find the one perfect spot that will let me click. Any Idea what may be causing this or how to fix it.

XAML Snipit:

```
Window x:Class="qaTrackingDatabase.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="QA Tracking DB Update Tool" Height="715.963" MinHeight="715.983" Width="868.283" MinWidth="878.283" Icon="rm12icon.ico" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<Grid Margin="0,0,-8,3">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDFEDF7" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDFECF7" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <TabControl  Name="myTabControl" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" Background="#FFDFECF7">
        <TabItem x:Name="Branch" Header="Branch" MinWidth="170" MinHeight="25">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" MaxHeight="238" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid>
                    <RadioButton Name="Add" Content="Add" Margin="25,28,0,150" Checked="Branch_RadioBtns_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="619"/>
                    <RadioButton Name="Delete" Content="Delete" Margin="25,99,202,84"  Checked="Branch_RadioBtns_Checked" />
                    <TextBox Name="Add_Name_txtBox" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Add, Path=IsChecked}" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter Name" Width="230" Margin="352,53,264,0" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" Margin="250,57,490,158"> Branch Name:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Name="Dproduct_Combo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Delete, Path=IsChecked}" Text="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="111,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="Get_Dproduct_Branch"/>
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" Margin="41,123,740,92"> Product:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Name="Aproduct_Combo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Add, Path=IsChecked}" Text="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="111,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"/>
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" Margin="41,57,740,150"> Product:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" Margin="250,123,490,91"> Select Branch:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Name="Dbranch_Combo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Delete, Path=IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="351,119,0,0"/>
                    <Button Content="Commit&#xD;&#xA;Changes" FontFamily="Levenim MT" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Click="Branch_Commit_Changes" Margin="637,177,10,10" MaxHeight="49" MaxWidth="189"  MinHeight="49" MinWidth="189" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something very strange going on with your Margin/Height/Width values. I'd strongly suggest that you start using grid rows and columns. In the long run you'll find that everything resizes and works much better in XAML when you do.

Here's an update the tab control in your window.

```
    <TabControl  Name="myTabControl" Margin="0" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" Background="#FFDFECF7">
        <TabItem x:Name="Branch" Header="Branch" MinWidth="170" MinHeight="25">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5" Name="Add" Content="Add" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" > Product:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Name="Aproduct_Combo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Add, Path=IsChecked}" Text="Select" Width="119"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" > Branch Name:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5" Name="Add_Name_txtBox" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Add, Path=IsChecked}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter Name" Width="230" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Background="White" />
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Name="Delete" Content="Delete"  />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" > Product:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Name="Dproduct_Combo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Delete, Path=IsChecked}" Text="Select" Width="119" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Levenim MT" > Select Branch:</TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5" Name="Dbranch_Combo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Delete, Path=IsChecked}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5" Content="Commit&#xD;&#xA;Changes" FontFamily="Levenim MT" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: This Answers my question by getting the objects to be focusable, but now none of my background code populates any of the comboboxes. Do you have to reference them in different ways when using Row and Column Definitions?

Comment: Sorry I removed the events in the XAML during my testing since I didn't have your code behind, you just need to add your event handlers back into the XAML (i.e. Checked="Branch_RadioBtns_Checked", etc...)

Comment: Haha, I saw that after I made the comment. but this solved my question. i still dont know what it is that's causing them not to be focusable in the first place, but its better practice to use grid definitions anyways. The only change I made, since all my controls had set widths, heights, and margins, I only needed one row and one column definition, and I didnt have to assign each control to it since they automatically default to the first one if not specified.